# How to restart asyncio thread?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

How can I restart an asyncio loop? I'm listening to a websocket with asyncio. I want to stop listening, and restart the whole loop. How can I do that? My try below does not work

```
async def start_websocket(streams):
    print("using streams {}".format(streams))
    await asyncio.sleep(30)


def _start_loop(loop, ws):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(ws)
    except CancelledError:
        pass


for streams in ["a", "b"]:
    ws = start_websocket(streams)  # coroutine
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    # in case of already running, cancel websocket
    if loop.is_running():
        [t.cancel() for t in asyncio.Task.all_tasks()]

    # restart websocket
    Thread(target=_start_loop, args=(loop, ws)).start()
    time.sleep(2)
```

I'm getting

```
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
```

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially stop the loop(`loop.stop()` or `loop.close()`) and create a new one via `loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()`

Another option would be to create a custom event loop policy: [Loop Policy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-policy.html#asyncio-policies)

Comment: i've made the example self contained. Do you have some example code?

Answer (score 0):

```
    print("using streams {}".format(streams))
    await asyncio.sleep(30)


def _start_loop(loop, ws):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(ws)
    except CancelledError:
        pass


for streams in ["a", "b"]:
    ws = start_websocket(streams)  # coroutine
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    # in case of already running, cancel websocket
    if loop.is_running():
        [t.cancel() for t in asyncio.Task.all_tasks()]
    try:
      loop.close() #docs say "The loop must not be running when this function is called. "
    except:
      loop.stop() 
    # restart websocket
    Thread(target=_start_loop, args=(loop, ws)).start()
    time.sleep(2)
```

This should fix the error that you've previously gotten

Comment: thanks this gives error: RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

Answer (score 0):

```
async def subtask(s):
    while True:
        print("running task {}".format(s))
        await asyncio.sleep(5)

async def start_websocket(streams):
    print("using streams {}".format(streams))
    asyncio.ensure_future(subtask(streams+"1"))
    asyncio.ensure_future(subtask(streams+"2"))
    try:
        while True:
            print("running task {}".format(streams))
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
    except CancelledError:
        print("cancelled task {}".format(streams))

def _start_loop(loop):

    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()


for streams in ["a", "b", "c"]:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    if not loop.is_running():
        Thread(target=_start_loop, args=(loop,)).start()
    else:
        for t in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
            t.cancel()

    loop.create_task(start_websocket(streams))
    time.sleep(10)
    print("finished {}".format(streams))

time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: Could you add some explanatory text regarding the difference between the original code and the new version, so that a future reader can learn from it?